# how to select number of element values randomly in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, exslt

I want to select 30% of values randomly from a XML.As Here is 10 values so , i have to select 3 values randomly.

i have a xml.

```
<xml>
    <value>A</value>
    <value>B</value>
    <value>C</value>
    <value>D</value>
    <value>E</value>
    <value>F</value>
    <value>G</value>
    <value>H</value>
    <value>I</value>
    <value>J</value>
</xml>
```

I need this value.

```
<xml>
    <value>E</value>
    <value>I</value>
    <value>J</value>
</xml>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor will you be using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://exslt.org/random/functions/random-sequence/index.html

Comment: @michael.hor257k  It's XSLT 1.0

Comment: Does the used XSLT 1 processor have support for the EXSLT functions? Or which one is it exactly?

Comment: @PierreFrançois I think XSLT 1.0 does not support EXSLT,


 XSLT transformation error occured [Illegal value: random:random-sequence used for QNAME attribute: name

Comment: @RudraprasadPradhan I asked which XSLT processor, not which version of XSLT. If you don't know, find out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

Comment: We still do not know which XSLT processor the OP is using.

Comment: xslt processor 1.0

Comment: @RudraprasadPradhan You are wasting time by repeating the answer you have already given, instead of answering the question you were asked - by now it's 3 times, I think.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: the OP clearly doesn't understand our question.

Comment: @PierreFrançois I provided a link to the method to get the answer. Not sure what else I can do.

Comment: @RudraprasadPradhan: I will try to reformulate the questions everybody is asking you. You have an XML file as input. You want another XML file as output. Which software or which command do you issue at the shell command line to tell the computer that he has to process the first file into the second one? `xsltproc`? A `javascript` program? A PHP program? A browser?

Comment: @PierreFrançois François This is my xslt processor..
Apache Software Foundation1.0

Comment: @RudraprasadPradhan: I deduce from your answer that you use the XSLT processor `Xalan`, which is from the Apache Fondation and is a XSLT 1.0 processor. You can generate random numbers outside Xalan and then pass these through some parameters to `Xalan` with the option `-p`. If you show a minimal attempt to code something, we can help you. But nobody will be able to help you if you don't give more details.

Answer (score 0):

In a modern XSLT 3 implementation supporting the `random-number-generator` function you can use e.g. `random-number-generator()?permute(/xml/value)[position() = 1 to 3]`:

```
let $xml := <xml>
<value>A</value>
<value>B</value>
<value>C</value>
<value>D</value>
<value>E</value>
<value>F</value>
<value>G</value>
<value>H</value>
<value>I</value>
<value>J</value>
</xml>,
$values := $xml/value,
$length := xs:integer(count($values) * .3)
return random-number-generator()?permute($values)[position() = 1 to $length]
```

So you need an XSLT 3 processor like Saxon 10 in any edition or Saxon 9 PE or EE or AltovaXML 2017 R3 or later.

In XSLT 1, if you have support for EXSLT's `math:random`, you can use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xml">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="value[position() &lt; 4]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="value">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="pos" select="floor(math:random() * 10 + 1)"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="../value[$pos]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/93Fbify

Comment: You do not necessarily need an XSLT 3 processor. There are other ways to generate a random.number.

Comment: can it be possible at xslt 1.0?'

Comment: Not possible in XSLT 1.0 without some kind of extension functions.

Comment: Thank You @Martin , 
I don't have support for EXSLT. I want to do via XSLT 1.0

Comment: @MichaelKay You do not necessarily need an extension function. A seed supplied from outside may suffice. I have seen suggestions to use some metric of the input XML as the seed, but I don't like the odds of that.

Comment: Okay  , Is it possible via xslt 2.0 ?

Comment: Can you please help me to get xslt select between two position ..

Like this is xslt select between two numbers.

   <xsl:template match="value[. &lt; 1 or . &gt; 2]"/>

I want same kind of functionality for 2 positions.